# $\frac{\sqrt{26} - \sqrt{13} - \sqrt{2}+1}{\sqrt{13} -1 }= ? $

Tags: radicals

$$\frac{\sqrt{26} - \sqrt{13} - \sqrt{2}+1}{\sqrt{13} -1 }= ? $$

**My attempt:**

$$\frac {\sqrt{2}. \sqrt{13} - \sqrt{13}-2 +1}{2} \tag 1$$
Which equals to
$$\frac {\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{13} +1} \tag 2 = ...$$

Waiting for your helps.

Comment: Typesetting tip:  To obtain $\sqrt{13}$, type \sqrt{13} when you are in math mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}\frac{\sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt{13}-\sqrt{13}-\sqrt2+1}{\sqrt{13}-1}&=\frac{\sqrt{13}(\sqrt 2 -1)-1 (\sqrt2-1)}{\sqrt{13}-1}\\&=\frac{(\sqrt{13}-1)(\sqrt 2-1)}{\sqrt{13}-1}\\&=\sqrt2-1
\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain the first step?

Comment: @Liam I have applied the property $ab-b=(a-1)b$. Here $b=\sqrt{13}$ and $a=\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @user8734617 Thanks for editing!

Comment: I still didn't get that property.

Comment: @Liam how will you split $10 \cdot (5+3)$ Can't you write it as $10 \cdot 5+ 10 \cdot 3$. We can, right? Similarly, $a(b+c)=ab+ac$. Just apply this in reverse

Comment: Can you show it on these values? What I didn't get is $-1(\sqrt 2 -1)$

Comment: @Liam $\sqrt{13}(\sqrt2 -1) = \sqrt{13} \cdot \sqrt 2- \sqrt{13} \cdot 1 = \sqrt{13} \cdot \sqrt{2}-\sqrt{13}= \sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt{13} -\sqrt {13}$.  Just go reverse in each step. I hope you'll understand.

Comment: I got that, what I didn't get is $-1(\sqrt 2 - 1)$. Oh sorry I got it now!! am too grateful, thank you

Comment: Use $a-b=-(b-a)$.  $$-\sqrt2+1=-(\sqrt 2+1)$$. @Liam

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{\sqrt 2-1}{\sqrt{13}+1}=\dfrac{\sqrt 2-1}{\sqrt{13}+1}\dfrac{\sqrt {13}-1}{\sqrt{13}-1}=\dfrac{1}{12}(\sqrt2-1)(\sqrt{13}-1)=\dfrac{1}{12}(\sqrt{26}-\sqrt{13}-\sqrt{2}+1)$$

Comment: use that $$\sqrt{26}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{13}$$